# troubles with included files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, include, undefined-symbol

I have a problem with include files in Xcode, while I am compiling a gstreamer project.
The header search path contains :
"/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/0.10/Headers"

When I am including a header file :
`#include <gst/gst.h>` the CMD+click function to follow the link answer me " SYMBOL NOT FOUND ".

Moreover, I have compilation problems, I am sure the reason is here.

Thanks

Comment: just asking, did you add the framework to the project?

Comment: yes it is included, with the yellow toolbox on the project navigator